# Android studio AVD error unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, android-virtual-device

I am working on application in Android Studio login application simple login page when i test it the app starts and when I press sing in button show this message "unfortunately myapp has stopped"
I want to solve this problem 
this my code 
Mainactivity.java

```
package kandl.com.g99.g5080.mohannedinfo;

 import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
//Toolbar
//toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
//setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//Toolbar

public void loginOnClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.login) {
        EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
        String str = a.getText().toString();


        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
        i.putExtra("Username", str);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
}
```

display.java
to display welcome to user another Activity

```
 package kandl.com.g99.g5080.mohannedinfo;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class Display extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVusername);
    tv.setText(username);
   }
 }
```

Comment: you mean in button XML

Comment: I have many red lines in logcat

Comment: and have you defined it in xml button onclick attribute?

Comment: make onclick in XML and make this function in main activity VIEW v

Comment: logcat is too long website tell me this

Comment: have you define yout display acitivity in manifest?

Comment: i didn't make anything in manifest

Answer (score 0):

register your `Display` `activity` in your manifest file inside `<application></application>` tag

```
<activity  android:name=".Display" />
```